# \today as argument in hypersetup leads to an error

Tags: hyperref, date, hyperxmp

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperxmp,hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfdate={\today}}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I get as error message:

```
! Argument of \hyxmp@pdf@to@xmp@date has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \hypersetup{pdfdate={\today}}
```

Is it a bug from `hyperref`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the hyperxmp documentation says, `pdfdate` must be given in a specific format:

> It must be specified in either xmp format or PDF format

So \today won't work. But the documentation also says that the default value of pdfdate is  the date the document was built. So using `pdfdate=\today` is quite unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you - it worked until the last update of hyperxmp - but since it is unnecessary I can omit it anyways.